# Maven complete surefire-report including passed tests logging events

Tags: maven, junit, report, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to generate a report using surefire-report plugin of maven which will give me a detailed report of all the tests that ran with the log events that were logged during each test run instead of just the events where my test failed. This will also give me the full context where my test failed.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
        <artifactId>SampleTests</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>sampleTests</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>com/mypackage/**</include>
          </includes>
          <test>**/*Tests</test>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>report-only</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

And i use mvn surefire-report:report to generate the report here.
So I want to know if there is anything additional that i can do so as to see a detailed report of what happened during the tests run?

Answer (score 0):

As a reference from the [maven site](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/)

[surefire-report:report](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html) Generates the test results report into HTML format.
[surefire-report:report-only](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-only-mojo.html) This goal does not run the tests, it only builds the reports.

You are trying the **report-only**. Try the other one **report** as a goal

Comment: the report-only and report as you said are only just for defining whether to run the tests or not run the tests. It has nothing to do with the log events in the tests. The thing that i want to achieve is that I see a complete log of the events that happen during the run which you see when you run mvn surefire-report:report from cmd printer in the report.

Comment: But, This kinda reports comes by default in the target folder when you build a project with sure fire plugin. I am afraid you didn't check that. And I am not sure whether this is what you need, Maven-jxr-plugin with the surefire. It prints the source code reference of the test case failure.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ant to get to what I needed. Thanks to this blog: http://blog.varunin.com/2010/03/ant-script-for-generating-junit-report.html#comment-form

If you want to get a detailed report of all the test events then please use this

Comment: OP was requesting maven help, this post talks of ant and is of no help

Comment: This post is OP I believe.